# "What is a thing?" -- Coecke versus Kastner

Tags: quantum-interpretations

The subject's from Coecke's https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0417 and my question's essentially to "compare and contrast" that with Kastner's https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.09034 which appeared today.

Seems to me that Coecke's topos-theoretic, linguistic-like approach is what Kastner's referring to as the epistemic aspects of distinguishability, whereas her quantum statistics approach emphasizes (what she's calling) the ontological individuality aspects.

As far as compare-and-contrast is concerned, I noted that Kastner's bibliography contains zero references to any of the topos approaches (which I think Coecke et al originated). And, of course (retrocausality notwithstanding:), Coecke doesn't reference Kastner. But I've only just barely scratched the surface of this stuff, and can't see for myself what kind of Coecke$\Leftrightarrow$Kastner relationships/arrows/morphisms/whatever might be constructed. Any ideas, by which I mean formal associations/correspondences in that $\Leftrightarrow$ sense, about that?

Comment: Now IMO that's a good question - the Coecke paper  certainly something I plan to read. Not sure how well this question will be received; I hope it is.

Comment: Thanks, @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Yeah, "plan to read". I've read about half of its 207 pages, but (in my case at least) read$\not=$understand (I'm hoping https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.5660 provides slightly more accessible prerequisites). By the way, if you're interested in Coecke's approach, you may find lots of additional interesting stuff in https://books.google.com/books?id=-vfvCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover I've found about half the contributions freely (and legitimately) downloadable online.